# KnockoutJS: parameterize data-bind

Tags: javascript, user-interface, knockout.js, frontend

I want to use a variable for the data-bind on my input element. Here is what I have tried:

```
<!--  ko foreach: [
    {dataBind: {value: thing1}, txt: 'thing Name:'},
    {dataBind: {maskedThing: thing2}, txt: 'thing Amount:'},
    {dataBind: {value: thing3}, txt: 'thing3 Name:'}
] -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label pull-left"><span data-bind="text: txt"></span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="$data.dataBind">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The txt: variable works: it is used as the label. However, the "$data.dataBind" usage never gets evaluated, it just stays as a string. How can I get the data-bind of the input element to be parameterized in this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience i believe this is not possible the way you are trying to achieve it.
To do it properly you could create a custom component so that you can control what happens based on the passed object/param

Right now, to make it work as you are fast, you can change your html and add an `if` binding to control what gets rendered, along with a flag on your objects like so:

```
....
    {dataBind: {value: thing1}, txt: 'thing Name:', isMasked: false},
    {dataBind: {maskedThing: thing2}, txt: 'thing Amount:', isMasked: true},
    {dataBind: {value: thing3}, txt: 'thing3 Name:', isMasked: false}
....           
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="if: isMasked, maskedThing: txt">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="ifnot: isMasked, value: txt">
```

On each iteration either input will  get render and binded, depending on the flag of the object.